# Are there any interactive shells for Windows Script Host environment

Tags: windows, scripting

As the title suggests, I am looking for a Python like interactive shell for Windows Script Host. I want to analyze for example, the object that is returned by `GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_process")`. Currently I need to search on Google and refer to the online documentation. It will be far easier if I could just inspect the object for properties and methods, much like Python provides. I tried to install [ActiveScript Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/activescript-shell/9nblggh532gb) which was promising, but it refuses to run and the main website of the application is no longer up.

Comment: The code snippet you've provided, is that VBScript?

Comment: The code snippet is understood by the Windows Script Host Engine. So VBScript and JScript both can make that particular call.